# Should my libraries be aware of Reactive Extensions?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I am getting more and more interested in Reactive Extensions for .NET. Since my application are involves data-acquisition systems, most probably even the core classes and concepts of my domain libraries would benefit of using Rx concepts.

My doubt is: should I "contaminate" my domain model with Rx types and interfaces? Or should I keep it "clean", using Rx only in client code?

In one hand, Clean Architecture proponents (Uncle Bob mostly) advocates that "thou shalt not depend on the framework", and that makes sense.

On the other hand, I am already developing in .NET, which is itself a framework, and Rx seems to have come to stay. For example, David West advocates that 80% of the classes in a system should come from the libs, and only about 20% should be hand-coded and specific to the system itself. I believe this is why Python is so successful, too, the "batteries included" approach, library-wise.

So, pragmatically speaking, which is the de-facto way of using Rx in your cake: do you sprinkle it over, or mix it right into the dough?

Comment: Interesting, but possibly opinionated. I would not publicly expose RX (or RX dependent types) in the core library and perhaps supply a bunch of extension methods in a separate library that allow users to easily bridge the gap (in the vein of the `ToObservable` extension method available for `Task<T>`)

Comment: @spender thanks for the feedback. Wouldn't "supply a bunch of extension methods in a separate library" be exactely what Rx is about to begin with? That's why I'm asking, it looks like I _shoudn't_ need to depend on Rx, it seems to have been done purposely as an extension library exactely for that, maybe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As with all answers to questions of this nature; "it depends".

What does it depend on?

- Who is the target consumer or your library?
- What is the nature of the problem you are solving?

If your target consumers are internal, or even better, just you, then do what you like. Seriously.

However if others will use your library (e.g. public, lives on Nuget) then you have other considerations.
If the nature of your library is a sprinkling of Async methods and you just happen to like Rx more than Task, then I would actually err on keeping Task. If you take a dependency on Rx, then so will your clients. If you client happens to take a dependency on another lib that has a dependency on a different version of Rx, then well, that can be fun.

However if your library is surfacing a truly "streaming" set of data points, then exposing those as IObservable can be useful. If you however don't use Rx internally, then again, I would err away from the Rx dependency. You can expose a method with callback parameters or a normal old .NET event member. If a consumer wants to use Rx, then `Observable.Create` will easily adapt your API into Rx.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I think I'm going into the second approach (Rx all the way), since my core lib actually "is surfacing a truly "streaming" set of data points", I am an application developer (as opposed to library developer), and I am already using so many NuGet packages that it would be silly to keep short of this one, considering the large impact I am expecting to obtain in expressiveness and thread safety. Thanks again!